# Выдает ошибку: Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x0120560E в ProblemE-olympTemp.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу 0xFDFDFE01.

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
int n, i, j, count_column, count_row, counter = 0, more_counter = 0, test;
cin >> n >> i >> j;
int **arr = new int*[n];
for (count_column = 0; count_column < n; count_column++)
    arr[count_column] = new int[n];
count_row = 0;
count_column = 0;
while (counter <= n / 2 + n % 2) {
    for (count_column = counter; count_column < n - counter; count_column++) {
        more_counter++;
        arr[count_column][counter] = more_counter;
        if (count_row + 1 == i && count_column + 1 == j) {
            cout << arr[count_column][count_row];
            for (counter = 0; counter < n; counter++)
                delete[]arr[counter];
            delete[] arr;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    for (count_row = counter + 1; count_row < n - counter; count_row++) {
        more_counter++;
        arr[count_column][count_row] = more_counter;
        if (count_row + 1 == i && count_column + 1 == j) {
            cout << arr[count_column][count_row];
            for (counter = 0; counter < n; counter++)
                delete[]arr[counter];
            delete[] arr;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    for (count_column - 1; count_column >= counter + 1; count_column--) {
        more_counter++;
        arr[count_column][count_row] = more_counter;
        if (count_row + 1 == i && count_column + 1 == j) {
            cout << arr[count_column][count_row];
            for (counter = 0; counter < n; counter++)
                delete[]arr[counter];
            delete[] arr;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    for (count_row; count_row > counter + 1; count_row--) {
        more_counter++;
        arr[count_column][count_row] = more_counter;
        if (count_row  + 1== i && count_column + 1 == j) {
            cout << arr[count_column][count_row];
            for (counter = 0; counter < n; counter++)
                delete[]arr[counter];
            delete[] arr;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    counter++;
}
cout << arr[count_column][count_row];
for (counter = 0; counter < n; counter++)
    delete[]arr[counter];
delete[] arr;
system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Если бы вы запустили отладчик - нашли бы проблему сами. В строке 30

`arr[count_column][count_row] = more_counter;`

значение `count_column` остается от предыдущего цикла, т.е. равняется `n - counter`. Если `counter` равен нулю, то `count_column` равен `n` и закономерно происходит  выход за пределы массива.